Ubuntu upgraded to 24.04, and Remmina can't open SSH tunnels anymore
new to this site...
I have just upgraded my Ubuntu 22.04.x release to the new 24.04.1 one.
I work from home, connecting to my work PC with Remmina; it creates a SSH tunnel on our gateway on Internet, and then connects to the VNC server on my work PC.
I have used this setup for the last 4 years, and it has always worked as a charm.
Today I upgraded my Ubuntu release on my home PC, and the first thing I checked was Remmina, of course. The connection parameters to my work PC are saved, and when I launched it Remmina showed me this error: "Could not resolve hostname xxx to IP v6".
IP v6 on my home PC (and the gateway it should connect to) is disabled.
The gateway name is resolved using the command host, and I can connect to it with SSH using both its name and its IP v4 address.
Remmina shows the same error if I use both the name or the IP for the gateway.
Selecting or deselecting the "Analyze ~/.ssh/config" in the Preferences/SSH Options makes no differences (the names could be slightly different, I am translating them in English.
The Remmina version is 1.4.35+dsfg, the package source is the Ubuntu-noble-main (deb) repo.
Can anybody help me to make Remmina and me work again?
Thank you and best regards
Pierluigi
